# if i have 5 buttons with same CLASS, can i use javascript onclick to get ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 5 buttons set up with the same class "deletebutton"

but each deleton button has a unique purpose ( delete different ID )

```
$(".deletebutton").click(function (e){
    document.getElementById("abc").href="delete.php?adID="; + ID of button clicked
});
```

what i need to do is modify the link of another button, based on the ID of the button clicked.

```
<a  id="Delete" href="remove.php?adID=" >Confirm</a>
```

I have been having an issue with this, and think its because my "deletebutton" function running off the CLASS of the button only knows the class not the ID of the specifc button clicked? thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  any of these to get id `this.id` or `e.target.id` or `$(this).attr("id")`

```
$(".deletebutton").click(function (e){
    document.getElementById("abc").href="delete.php?"+ this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to access the id of a particular element, you will have to use `$(this).attr('id')`, but 
the recommended way or a best practice to do this is to use HTML 5 Data Attributes. Instead of using the `ID` you can store them as data attributes.

```
<a class='action'  data-mode="NEW" data-id='7' href="new.php?adID=" >New</a>
<a class='action' data-mode="DELETE" data-id='7' href="remove.php?adID=" >Delete</a>
<a class='action' data-mode="UPDATE" data-id='7' href="update.php?adID=" >Update</a>
```

So you can access them using the class or using the data attribute itself.

```
$('.action').on('click',function(e){
  var mode = $(this).data('mode');
  //This will output NEW/DELETE/UPDATE based on what you clicked

  var id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

or

```
$('[data-mode]').on('click',function(e){
  var mode = $(this).data('mode');
  //This will output NEW/DELETE/UPDATE based on what you clicked

  var id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

Data Attributes provides so much flexibility to store additional information on the DOM and also provides easier way to access them.

Take a look at http://bit.ly/1nVOFgj for more information on how to use data attributes and how it helps. Hope this helps.

Comment: cool thanks, ive been coding in SQL for about 4 years and other languages for many more ( im 22 ). I just got a job as a freelancer for this start up business thats based on a web app. I kind of lied in the interview towards my PHP skills, but this isnt so bad because im working with some source code.